# Fedora 20 not finding USB stick when booting

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, fedora

Fedora 20 system has a USB stick used to back up important files nightly.

When I reboot the system it does not find the USB stick. If I then pull the stick out and plug it back in, the system finds it and calls it /dev/sdg.  How can I make it find the stick on boot?

Or, how can I make the system find the stick after boot without unplug/plug?

Command line or config file answers preferred. I'm not a GUI guy.

Note: this is *not* about booting *from* the USB stick.  The systems boots from hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps (with root permissions in command line):

1. `touch /etc/rc.local`
2. `chmod +x /etc/rc.local`
3. `nano /etc/rc.local #or any other editor you want`
4. Add `#!/bin/bash` to the top of the file.
5. Add `mount -a` the the next line of the file
6. Add `exit 0` to the next line of the file.

Now the file (/etc/rc.local) should look like this (you can add comments for clarification):

```
#bin/bash
mount -a
exit 0
```

If your file looks like this, save. The next time you reboot, your usb should be mounted.

Comment: It's not mounting the USB stick that's a problem - it's the system not finding it at all.  After boot, the system says there is no /dev/sdg until the stick is unplugged and plugged back in.